# How to fix ng-lz-string error after update to Angular 9+? [with answer]

Tags: angular

I was updating application from version 8 to version 9.1.13 after running `cmd /C "set "NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1" && npx @angular/cli@9 update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9"` command console threw `Package "ng-lz-string" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.8.4", would install "0.10.3")`
It was forced with `--force` flag to handle this later. So I did. Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution was switching from dedicated `ng-lz-string` package to `lz-string` that won't be an issue for Ivy compiler.

Steps to do:

1. Install

```
    npm i lz-string -S 

    npm i @types/lz-string  -D
```

2. Create new file (name whatever You'd like)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { compress, decompress } from 'lz-string';

@Injectable()
export class CompressionService {
  compressString(data: string): string {
    return compress(data);
  }
  compressObject(data: any): string {
    return compress(JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  decompressString(compressed: string): string {
    return decompress(compressed);
  }
  decompressObject(compressed: string): any {
    return JSON.parse(decompress(compressed));
  }
}
```

3. Add declaration

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ...
    CompressionService
  ],
```

4. Than switch from `LZStringService` to You custom in every spot You have used it

That's it!

Credit goes for: https://github.com/shailendragusain/ng-lz-string/issues/9#issuecomment-450728491

Wasn't easy to find this and to make this work but this info should be spreaded out.

Cheers!